# Google Action Console(Cloud function editor) How to ask something to the user

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

Hi i'am working with google assistant, i'am using Action Builder in the Google Action Console because it seemed easy to use. I red the documentation here https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview and i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1hxvniJ18s and i was able to understand the basic of how it's work and how to use Webhook. The problem is that i can give answer to the user but i can't ask him question. here is how i do it :

```
    app.handle('myhandler', (conv) => {
  conv.add('Hello world from fulfillment');
});
```

This work and when i call my webhook from my scene i get the response from the webhook. But i couldn't find how to ask something to the user. I saw that some people could use `conv.ask('my question');` But when I do and I test it in the Action Console Simulator, i get an error :
Unsuccessful webhook call due to client issue:

> Error querying agent endpoint. State: URL_UNREACHABLE, reason:
> UNREACHABLE_5xx.

and in the webhookResponse i got :

> conv.ask is not a function

I have been looking a lot of topic and it seem that is DialogFlow from google cloud, but it seemed harder to implement and i didn't know if i could link it to my Action build ...

My question is how can i ask a question (and in a second time add suggestions) using Google action Console and the Could functions editor integrated in the webhook? And if it's not possible do i have to restart all my google assistant project from 0 in Dialogflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are following tutorials on using Actions Builder, which is slightly different from Dialogflow in a few ways. One such example is that the `.ask` method is not used in DF. Instead, you use the `.add` method. They are fundamentally equivalent for each platform. So you should keep using `.add` for your question and also for your suggestion chips:

```js
conv.add('What is your favorite color?')
conv.add(new Suggestion({title: 'My Suggestion Title'}))
```

**EDIT**

Don't forget to add `const {Suggestion} = require('@assistant/conversation');` as include

Comment: Thanks that worked but don't forget to add const {Suggestion} = require('@assistant/conversation'); as include or you will get an error as suggestion is not defined. can you also give me the link of the doc where you found it ?

Comment: There's a mention of the suggestions in [the Prompts section of the docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts#suggestions) and the [library reference docs](https://actions-on-google.github.io/assistant-conversation-nodejs/3.7.0/classes/conversation_prompt_suggestion.suggestion.html).